# Read a sample from sas7bdat file in R

Tags: r, sas

I have a sas7bdat file of size around 80 GB. Since my pc has a memory of 4 GB the only way I can see is reading some of its rows. I tried using the sas7bdat package in R which gives the error "big endian files are not supported"
The read_sas() function in haven seems to work but the function supports reading specific columns only while I need to read any subset of rows with all columns. For example, it will be fine if I can read 1% of the data to understand it.
Is there any way to do this? Any package which can work?
Later on I plan to read parts of the file and divide it into 100 or so sections

Comment: Is this a commercial, research, educational or not for profit type work?

Comment: I am trying it out for educational purposes. I don't have a sas licence

Comment: SAS is free for educational purposes. See SAS Analytics U and you can download the software. 80GB is still big, so I do recommend switching your work folder to a shared location rather than the default but you'll be able to process it there. Or at least read it in and export it back out to a txt or whatever form you want.

Comment: Is there an alternative which does not require using sas? Basically I want to handle this problem using R

Comment: The parsing logic is written in R syntax here: https://github.com/BioStatMatt/sas7bdat/blob/master/R/sas7bdat.R I think you could get frew k rows of raw data and run that without the 'magic number' check. Maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows you can use the [SAS Universal Viewer](https://support.sas.com/downloads/browse.htm?fil=&cat=74), which is free, and [export the dataset to CSV](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/univiewerug/63357/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p059cx9n04pe81n19zx13to3g6td.htm). Then you can import the CSV into R in more readable chunks [using this method](https://www.r-bloggers.com/opening-large-csv-files-in-r/).